# Calculate result from multi table in database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, calculated-field

I have a question in my VB.NET POS Development and could't find a solution myself. I'm currently using `VS2010` and `MS Access` as my database.

I have two database table as shown below:

`SalesReceipt(#Receipt_ID, Sales_Date, Receipt_Number, Customer_ID, Sales_BDiscount, Sales_ADiscount, Sales_Payment)`

`Customer(#Customer_ID, Customer_Name, Customer_Contact, Customer_Debt)`

NOTE : BDiscount = Before Discount / ADiscount = After Discount

In my system, one customer can have many SalesReceipt. Now my problem is how can I update the correct `Customer_Debt` for customer? My logic is update the respective customer's `Customer_Debt` by looping every row in `SalesReceipt` and calculate the debt by doing something like :

```
totalDebt = totalDebt + (Sales_Payment - Sales_ADiscount)
```

But I not sure how can I make sure it only loop and calculate the result for the selected customer only. How can I achieve this correctly in .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to calculate `totalDebt` per customer you can use query

```
SELECT Customer_ID, sum(Sales_Payment - Sales_ADiscount) as totalDebt FROM SalesReceipt
 GROUP BY Customer_ID
```

Result contains `totalDebts` aggregated by Customer_ID and can be used to update `Customer` (all the looping and calculating is done by a database engine).

The query can also update be more complex to do even update for you.

Comment: Sir, thanks for your answer! This is my query after testing around, is this correct : `SELECT Sum(Sales_ADiscount-Sales_Payment) AS totalDebt FROM SalesReceipt GROUP BY SalesReceipt.Customer_ID = ?` ? It will receive a parameter for Customer_ID.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just write a query in your Access db that performs your calculation (Sales_Payment - Sales_ADiscount) on your SalesReceipt table grouped by CustomerID?